# Detect numeric variables of a dataset and aggreagate them based on shiny widget selection of a categorical variable

Tags: r, shiny

In my `shiny` app I want to select one of my categorical variables and then detect and aggregate the numerical columns based on that selection.

```
## app.R ##
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinyjs)
library(htmlwidgets)
library(DT)
ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(
    title="Task Managers' Workload Analysis",
    titleWidth = 400
    
  ),
  dashboardSidebar(
    selectInput("var","Select variable",choices = c("color","cut","clarity"),selected = "color")
  ),
  dashboardBody(
    dataTableOutput("table")
  )
)

server <- function(input, output,session) {
  output$table<-renderDataTable({
    datatable(
      D<-aggregate(diamonds, by = diamonds[[input$var]], FUN = sum)
      
    )
    
  })
} 

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use `across` to do this -

```
diamonds %>% summarise(across(where(is.numeric), sum), .by = input$var)
```

Complete code -

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinyjs)
library(htmlwidgets)
library(DT)
library(dplyr)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(
    title="Task Managers' Workload Analysis",
    titleWidth = 400
    
  ),
  dashboardSidebar(
    selectInput("var","Select variable",
        choices = c("color","cut","clarity"),selected = "color")
  ),
  dashboardBody(
    dataTableOutput("table")
  )
)

server <- function(input, output,session) {
  output$table<-renderDataTable({
    datatable(
      diamonds %>%
        summarise(across(where(is.numeric), sum), .by = input$var)
    )
    
  })
} 

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

Comment: while it seems to work in your video check the image that Im taking in my edit when I run it on my end

Comment: I think your `dplyr` version is outdated. My `packageVersion('dplyr')` is 1.1.2